# Complicated NHibernate Criteria With Left Outer Joins?

Tags: nhibernate, subquery, left-join

I'm very new to NHibernate. I wrote this using CreateSQLQuery but I'd like to move this to the NHibernate Criteria format if at all possible. My query looks like this:

```
select parent.ID as Id, ValueA.Total as ValueACount, ValueB.Total as ValueBCount
from ParentTable parent 
left outer join
(
  select count(*) as Total, ID 
  from ChildTable
  where state = 'ValueA' 
  group by ID
) ValueA on ValueA.ID = parent.ID
left outer join
(
  select count(*) as Total, ID
  from ChildTable
  where state = 'ValueB' 
  group by ID
) ValueB on ValueB.ID = parent.ID
```

I changed the table names/values to abstract it a bit. The code works as is, but this is the only query we have in the whole solution. I'd like to see if we can get rid of it.

Thank in advance to all who can help. If you want to give me a link to a really good web page that could help me, that's fine, too. I'll at least thumb you up :)

I've also seen somewhat similar questions. If you feel that some other question/answers would help me immensely, feel free to point me to it.

Answer (score 2):

you could try some linq fu

```
var results = from p in session.Query<Parent>()
              select new
              {
                  p.Id,
                  ValueACount = (from c1 in session.Query<Child>() where c1.State == "ValueA" && c1.Parent == p select c1).Count(),
                  ValueBCount = (from c2 in session.Query<Child>() where c2.State == "ValueB" && c2.Parent == p select c2).Count(),
              };
```

or using criteria

```
var results = session.CreateCriteria<Parent>("p")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("Id"))
        .Add(Projections.SubQuery(DetachedCriteria.For<Child>()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("State", "ValueA") && Restrictions.EqProperty("Parent", "p"))
            .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount())))
        .Add(Projections.SubQuery(DetachedCriteria.For<Child>()
            .Add(Restrictions.Eq("State", "ValueB") && Restrictions.EqProperty("Parent", "p"))
            .SetProjection(Projections.RowCount()))))
    .List();
```

Comment: I'm trying out the second thing right now. Seems to come back with no results. Not sure what's wrong. Whether it's your code that's wrong or my re-translation into my classes. My classes don't match up, field-for-field, with the tables. I then made some dummy classes with just the necessary properties to no avail. That didn't work. I noticed something with your code, however. You have "Restrictions.EqProperty('Parent', 'p')). Aren't those supposed to be the property names? I.e. "Id", "Id"?

Comment: i assumed the ids are one to many associations in the classes. you could post the classes for me to know better. my code should mimic the sql `Select id, (select Count(*) from child c1 where c1.parentId == p.id and c1.state = "valueA") from parent p`

Comment: I thought EqProperty was testing if the value on the right hand side was equal to the left hand side... The parameters are titled lhs and rhs, in the NHibernate metadata... You seem to be labeling them as table name and alias. Am I misunderstanding?

Comment: the eqproperty should be equivalent to `EqProperty("Parent.Id", "p.Id"))` which does compare two properties, one of the object-alias and one of the query